# Problem with the fourier transform of sinc

Tags: fourier-transform

I have to take the fourier transform of the following:

> $$h(t)= \begin{cases}             \frac{2\sin(300\pi t)}{\pi t}, & t
> > \ne 0 \\ 600, & t=0\end{cases}$$

So I used the two properties :

1. $\mathrm{rect}\left(\frac{t}{ \tau}\right) \xrightarrow{F.T.} \tau \mathrm{sinc}(\frac{\tau w}{2})$
2. $X(t) \xrightarrow{F.T.} 2\pi x(-w)$ (duality)

Here $F.T.$ means Fourier transform and $x(.)$ and $X(.)$ are fourier transform pairs and $\mathrm{rect}$ is :

$$\mathrm{rect}\left(\frac{t}{ \tau}\right) =\begin{cases}1, & |t| \leq \frac {\tau}{2}\\ 0, & otherwise \end{cases}$$

using them I got the $H(w)=2\pi\mathrm{rect}\left(\frac{w}{600\pi}\right)$

> But the given answer is:
>
> [image]  .
>
> That is $H(w)=2\mathrm{rect}\left(\frac{w}{600\pi}\right)$

Can someone please tell me what is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\mathrm{F.T.}\ \frac1\pi\mathrm{rect}(\frac{t}{600\pi}) = \frac1\pi600\pi\frac{\sin 300\pi w}{300\pi w}=2\frac{\sin 300\pi w}{\pi w}$$

$$\mathrm{F.T.}\ 2\frac{\sin 300\pi w}{\pi w}=2\pi\times\frac1\pi\mathrm{rect}(\frac{-w}{600\pi}) = 2\mathrm{rect}(\frac{w}{600\pi})$$

Comment: Ohh yeah, I missed the $\pi$ while converting it back. Thanks a lot. I took $\tau = 600$ instead of $600\pi$ in the amplitude of sinc and that was the problem.